# XML transformation - automize

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a routing - I need to edit (change the names of some elements, change the order of attributes, etc. ) an XML document (WSDL)

what would be the best way to automize this routine?

(some sort of script? java program?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can transform XML in a bunch of different ways. XSLT is a nice language created specifically for transforming XML, but you can do it in Java for sure. However, there's really no "best way".

Answer (score 0):

What may be very helpful for you and I believe is an industry standard is the XSLT transformaion. You can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

And learn how to use it in java here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html